# Django EmailValidator validating trailing dots

Tags: django, email-validation, django-1.9

I'm using Django 1.9, and `EmailValidator` seems to be validating trailing dots in email ids.

```
faulty_email = 'sid@h.in.'

user.email = faulty_email
user.save()
```

The above piece of code runs smoothly even though `email` is an `EmailField`, which has `EmailValidator`. The weird thing is, when I run the validation manually, it throws a `ValidationError`.

```
In [1]: from django.core.validators import validate_email

In [2]: faulty_email = 'sid@h.in.'

In [3]: validate_email(faulty_email)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValidationError        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-bdbbd57d5fe1> in <module>() 
----> 1 validate_email(faulty_email)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/validators.pyc in __call__(self, value)
    201             except UnicodeError:
    202                 pass
--> 203             raise ValidationError(self.message, code=self.code)
    204 
    205     def validate_domain_part(self, domain_part):

ValidationError: [u'Enter a valid email address.']
```

Does anyone know what the issue is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `save()` a model you’re only telling Django to commit the object to the database. It doesn’t validate during save. It will throw database exceptions if the fields don’t have the format expected by the database but an `EmailField` is just a charfield in your db. You should always [validate your models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) before saving them:

```
user.email = faulty_email
try:
    user.full_clean()
except ValidationError as e:
    print(e)
else:
    user.save()
```

When using a `ModelForm` you first validate the form (check `form.is_valid()`) then save it.

Comment: This (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.EmailField) says that `EmailField` validates the input.

Comment: Read the link about validating your model I posted in the answer. EmailField indeed sets a validator which validates the input when you validate your model (that’s what your link says). So `user.full_clean()` will throw a ValidationError. But save() never validates a model. You’ve just learned why you should always validate before saving.

Comment: Oh, okay.. thanks! Never knew Django did that! Thanks!